# SED substitute from variable containing special characters

Tags: unix, sed, ora-12170

I want to use SED in order to substitute a placeholder (##ERROR_MSG##) contained in a .txt file with the content of a variable ($ERROR_MSG)

here the command I use:

```
cat FILE.TXT  |  sed "s/##ERROR_MSG##/$ERROR_MSG/"
```

here what is contained in $ERROR_MSG (contains special characters and is multi line)

```
ERROR:
ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

ERROR:
ORA-12162: TNS:net service name is incorrectly specified

SP2-0306: Invalid option.
Usage: CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM}] [edition=value]] where    <logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
<proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
SP2-0157: unable to CONNECT to ORACLE after 3 attempts, exiting SQL*Plus
```

I recieve the following error message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated `s' command
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only robust way to do this, which will work with any value of $ERROR_MSG is:

```
awk -v old="##ERROR_MSG##" -v new="$ERROR_MSG" 's=index($0,old){$0 = substr($0,1,s) new substr($0,s+length(old))} 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sed "s+##ERROR_MSG##+$ERROR_MSG+" FILE.TXT
```

your line didn't work because the text in `$ERROR_MSG` contains slash `/`.

#### edit:

try this awk oneliner too:

```
awk -v t="$ERROR_MSG" '{sub(/##ERROR_MSG##/,t)}7' FILE.TXT
```

Comment: the solution is not working: i still recieve the same error message

Comment: @user3299274 is the text a very long line or multi-lines text?

Comment: @user3299274 try the awk one pls. (see answer)

Comment: The awk command is much more robust than the sed one but note that it will fail silently if `$ERROR_MSG` contains an ampersand (`&`). Try `echo "opq" | awk -v new="a&b" '{sub(/opq/,new)}1'` to see the failure.